# C++ OpenGL gluLookAt

Tags: c++, opengl

I have used the OpenGL command

`gluLookAt(eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, centerX, centerY, centerZ, upX, upY, upZ)`

I basically want to undo this operation so that my camera is back to the origin and facing `-z`.
I have read (on various sites) that a couple of basic glRotatef commands along with `glTranslate(-eyeY, -eyeY, -eyeZ)` can achieve the desired result.

But I am not able to figure out the what exactly the glRotate commands would be.

Answer (score 2):

Why not just reload the modelview matrix with the identity?  I.e:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
```

Comment: This only works if the model view matrix is the identity matrix before, but this might often be the case when using `gluLookAt`.

Comment: @Andre:  Agreed--from the context of the question it sounded like he had done a single `gluLookAt()` from the initial MV state.  I probably should have clarified that in my answer.  Your Push/Pop answer is certainly more general!

Answer (score 2):

You could save the matrix before with

```
glPushMatrix();
```

and restore it with

```
glPopMatrix();
```

but be aware of the performance implications. I guess that might be the reason why you want to reverse the call to `gluLookAt`. Maybe you can clarify that?

Comment: i want to reverse the call simply to do lighting(to be done in camera space), since I have the world coordinates of light. So, I just temporarily need to reverse it for a function call.

Answer (score 0):

OR rather than using extremely deprecated OpenGL stuff, write your own matrix classes and simply save a copy of it and then revert it after you've called your own Matrix::LookAt method :)

Comment: tried it...doesnt work....the point is I want to keep my light stationary while moving my camera around

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use gluLookAt(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, 1, 0)?

This puts the camera at 0 (eye position is 0, 0, 0) and sets the look at point to (0, 0, -1) which is along the -z axis, and sets the up vector to (0, 1, 0), which is along the y axis.

gluLookAt is not additive (not sure if this is the right word). Each call to gluLookAt sets the whole view matrix.

If you wanted to look at some position and then come back to the same position after moving around with gluLookAt, you could just save the eye, lookat point, and up vector and use them later.

Comment: tried it...doesnt work....the point is I want to keep my light stationary while moving my camera around

Comment: So why is the light not stationary? You only told us that you are using gluLookAt to move the camera, which is what it is supposed to do... Please show some relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

If ur code is like below :

```
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)

glLoadIdentity();

gluLookAt(......);
```

then modelview matrix effected by gluLookAt call. So first get modelview matrix by calling

```
float modelViewMat[16];

glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelViewMat);
```

Now find the invert matrix of modelViewMat.

```
float invertMat[16];

__gluInvertMatrixd(modelViewMat, invertMat);
```

Here is the code to get invert matrix.

```
int __gluInvertMatrixd(const float src[16], float inverse[16])
{
    int i, j, k, swap;
    float t;
    GLfloat temp[4][4];

    for (i=0; i<4; i++)
        for (j=0; j<4; j++)
            temp[i][j] = src[i*4+j];

    for(int i=0;i<16;i++)
        inverse[i] = 0;
    inverse[0] = inverse[5] = inverse[10] = inverse[15] = 1.0f;

    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
        swap = i;
        for (j = i + 1; j < 4; j++)
            if (fabs(temp[j][i]) > fabs(temp[i][i]))
                swap = j;

        if (swap != i) {
            //Swap rows.
            for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                t = temp[i][k];
                temp[i][k] = temp[swap][k];
                temp[swap][k] = t;

                t = inverse[i*4+k];
                inverse[i*4+k] = inverse[swap*4+k];
                inverse[swap*4+k] = t;
            }
        }

        if (temp[i][i] == 0)
            return 0;

        t = temp[i][i];
        for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            temp[i][k] /= t;
            inverse[i*4+k] /= t;
        }

        for (j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            if (j != i) {
                t = temp[j][i];
                for (k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                    temp[j][k] -= temp[i][k]*t;
                    inverse[j*4+k] -= inverse[i*4+k]*t;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return 1;
}
```

now multiply invertMat to any object matrix where u dont want to add modelview matrix effect.

Like :

```
glPushMatrix();

glMultMatrixf(invertMat);


glRotatef(...);

glTranslatef(...);

...
...

glDrawArrays(....);


glPopMatrix();
```

Comment: Please learn how to format code (hint: there's a question mark at the top of the input box :-)

Answer (score 0):

Since it appears your problem is lighting, I've got an old trick of the trade that might help ya here. I'm making a lot of assumptions here, but is it possible the reason you want to do this is because you don't want your lights moving around when your gluLookAt changes? I've had some trouble with this, and I've found that this works for that purpose:

```
glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW);
gluLookAt (ya know, stuff);
glLightfv (GL_LIGHTn, GL_POSITION, positionOfLight));
// ^ Putting your light positioning here will keep it in the right spot, relative only to the origin!
// Draw your stuff
```

Hope helped out a bit. Have fun.